# Running Gradle command from ant

Tags: gradle, grails, ant

The following is a snippet from my build.xml (which runs successfully)

```
<property name="gradlew" value="./gradlew"/>

<target name="test-functional" description="run functional tests">
    <antcall target="init"/>
    <antcall target="compile"/>
    <echo>Running functional tests...</echo>
    <exec executable="${gradlew}" failonerror="true">
        <arg value="iT"/>
        <!-- <arg value="iT --tests com.mygrailsapp.geb.** -Dgeb.env=firefox -Dgrails.server.port.http=8090"/> -->

    </exec>
</target>
```

But I only want to run my functional tests (under geb directory) with some additional options and so I comment in the second option in `<exec>` (which runs perfectly from the command line).
But from `ant`, I get the following;

```
 [exec] * What went wrong:
 [exec] Task 'iT --tests com.mygrailsapp.geb.**' not found in root project 'mygrailsapp'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<target name="test-functional" description="run functional tests">
    <antcall target="init"/>
    <antcall target="compile"/>
    <echo>Running functional tests...</echo>
    <exec executable="${gradlew}" failonerror="true">
        <arg value="iT"/>
        <arg value="--tests"/>
        <arg value="com.mygrailsapp.geb.**"/>
        <arg value="-Dgeb.env=firefox"/>
        <arg value="-Dgrails.server.port.http=8090"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```